# Create Directory in Android

Tags: android

Here is a [code](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/01/copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sd.html) that copy asset to SD card:

However, it only copy file to the root directory. If I change the code to this, then the file will be copy to mydirectory, but the condition is that "mydirectory" must be first created manually:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydirectory/"
                                    + files[i]);
```

My question is how should I modify the code so that a new directory can be created? I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130932/how-to-create-directory-automatically-on-sd-card) and came across creating file object and use `mkdirs()`

However I have really no idea on how to do it since I'm new in android development and do not have prior knowledge in programming.

I would appreciate if somebody can give me step by step guide on how to implement this.

Thank you.

Comment: You already have an answer in the link that you have provided.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517247/how-to-create-a-directory-in-external-sd-in-android-application/15517312#15517312. Check this link.

Comment: Yes, I know the link in provided have the answer, but the problem is I do not know how to implement it without step by step guide. I'm know nothing about programming. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the directory before you start adding files (obviously).

Use this in the file where you try to copy the so called "assets". See the comments:

```
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mydirectory/"); // this sets the filename of the new dir
File newDir = new File (filename); // this creates the File object (no directory yet)
if (!newDir.exists ())  // here we check whether the dir is already there
    newDir.mkdirs ()   // if not, then create all necessary directories and subdirectories to our new dir
```

Comment: I can simply put File newDir = new File (filename); under the above code? There is an error after I put it, which is filename can not be resolved to a variable? I learn android development by self learn. I'm really appreciate if you can provide step by step guide.

Comment: No, see that I added a declaration to your code. Also, I didn't finish the post last time. See my edit above.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can tell me the full step that I need to take for this. For instance where should I put your code? What should be added?

Comment: See my edited answer above. I also added comments. You basically put this code immediately before your other code.

Comment: Thank you. I know the answer you provided is working, but I don't have enough knowledge to do it myself. Probably I'll learn the complete android development starting from the basic in the future.

Answer (score 0):

it might help you..

```
boolean success = (new File("/sdcard/dirname")).mkdir(); 
if (!success)
{
    Log.w("directory not created", "directory not created");
}
```