# Android: Get data from server

Tags: android, url, android-parser

I want to develop an application. In which user enter a URL at run time. The XML is placed on server. So how to hit or get the data of that XML, so that i can parse the data and use that. The parsing i know. But how to get data directly i dont know.

So please suggest me how to hit url and get data with out web service.

Comment: have a edit text to allow user to enter url. get the url from edittext and make a http request. get the response parse  and display the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general

To make a request to the server, you can use a Asynctask or service.

For long running background operations use service.

An alternative to Asynctask is Robospice. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=robospice&oq=robospice&aqs=chrome.0.57j59l2j60j62l2.2501&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.

Making a soap request.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9EowBVgwSo.

Sample code with screen shot at [To use the tutorial in android 4.0.3 if had to work with AsynxTasc but i still dont work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521740/to-use-the-tutorial-in-android-4-0-3-if-had-to-work-with-asynxtasc-but-i-still-d/15521935#comment22060397_15521935).

Make a http request and get the response.

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html.

If your respone is xml parse the xml file

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/. Parse using domparser.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/. Parse using sax parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use Web services like JSON,SOAP

I prefer JSON

[JSON](http://json.org/)

How to create a [JSON response:](http://www.stevencharlesrobinson.com/sites/scrobinson.nsf/docs/Building%20a%20Simple%20RESTful%20Web%20Service%20to%20produce%20JSON%20using%20Jersey)

Android includes JSON classes such as JSONArray, JSONObject that can be used to interpret the response the Web Service will return. See more at: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: JSON is a webservice, who said it?

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara : I want to hit URL and copy the content in SD card with out the help of web service. So please suggest any method which can directly hit URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517247/how-to-create-a-directory-in-external-sd-in-android-application/15517312#15517312